# PHP - All classes and function in a single page

Tags: php

On php, i want to put all classes and functions on a single page. This page will be called throughout my project. is it recommendable or a bad practice?

Comment: That page will become your worst nightmare as time goes on. Take the time to split things correctly, it will help you in the long run.

Comment: If this classes will be bad designed - no matter ;)

Comment: This is why autoloaders were invented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. These files are often called "helpers". You could compile all the functions and classes that you need throughout your website in one file (e.g. `functions.php`). However, you should not forget to properly split your code apart into different files, to prevent creating a big mess. You can then use the functions/classes like so:

```
require 'functions.php';

$class = new MyClass(); // Use a class from the functions.php

myFunction(); // Use a function from the functions.php
```

But! Note that this file can now also be accessed via a URL. For example: http://example.com/functions.php. This can, in some cases, cause unwanted behavior. You can restrict the "direct access" to this file using .htaccess rules or simple place this code on top of the helper file:

`if(count(get_included_files()) == 1) die();`

Comment: thanks for the However part. also thanks for the security catch that you mention!

Answer (score 3):

It is bad practice. It is called a [big ball of mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud) anti pattern. Try to keep everything modularized. It will be more maintainable and readable. You will thank yourself later.